# How do I animate a polygon to spin in place with SVG?

Tags: html, svg

I have an 8 sided polygon that I want to spin clockwise at its center axis with text. Looking at MDN web docs shows a simple triangle spinning in place, but when I apply it to a polygon it doesn't quite work.

```html
<svg width="500" height="300">
  <polygon 
      points="25,5   75,5  100,30  100,80 75,105
      25,105  0,80  0, 30"
      style="stroke:gray; fill:#cc3333; stroke-width: 3;">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                          attributeType="XML"
                          type="rotate"
                          from="0 60 70"
                          to="360 60 70"
                          dur="10s"
                          repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </polygon>                    
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The centre of the polygon is at 50, 52.5 so you need to rotate round that.

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("polygon")[0].getBBox());
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="300">
  <polygon 
      points="25,5   75,5  100,30  100,80 75,105
      25,105  0,80  0, 30"
      style="stroke:gray; fill:#cc3333; stroke-width: 3;">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                          attributeType="XML"
                          type="rotate"
                          from="0 50 52.5"
                          to="360 50 52.5"
                          dur="10s"
                          repeatCount="indefinite">
</svg>
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you. I'm curious, how were you able to find the center point of the polygon?

Comment: @burnsie from the getBBox() call. Didn't you see that in the answer?

Comment: I see it. Thank you!